# how to add present absent value in new column using condition on runtime in datagridview windows form c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

i want to add attendance condition on runtime in datagridview..
for example if time is <= 09:45:00 then show present else if time is null then show absent in P/A column and then add in database using datagridview windows form c#

```
           try
{
              SqlCommand ucd = new SqlCommand("indiviual_attendence", ConnectionString.Getconnection());
              ucd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
              ucd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 2;
              ucd.Parameters.Add("@empcode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = value;
              SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(ucd);
              dt = new DataTable();
              sda.Fill(dt);
              if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
              {
                  textBox2.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
              }
              ConnectionString.closeconnection();
              if (textBox2.Text != "")
              {
                  cmd = new SqlCommand("indiviual_attendence", ConnectionString.Getconnection());
                              cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                             cmd.Parameters.Add("@id",SqlDbType.Int).Value = 3;
                             cmd.Parameters.Add("@empcode",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "%"+value;
                  SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                  dt = new DataTable();
                  sd.Fill(dt);
                  if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                  {
                      dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                      dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Code";
                      dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Name";
                      dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Department";
                      dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Year";
                      dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Month";
                      dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Day";
                      dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Time";
                      dataGridView1.Columns[7].HeaderText = "Status";
                      dataGridView1.Columns[8].HeaderText = "EMP/MACH-CODE";  
                      dataGridView1.Columns[9].HeaderText = "Attendance_id";
                      dataGridView1.Columns[9].Visible = false;
                     dataGridView1.Columns[10].HeaderText = "P/A";
                     // dataGridView1.Columns["Attendance_id"].Visible = false;
                      dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                      dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
                      dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
                      this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.GhostWhite;

                  }

                  ConnectionString.closeconnection();
              }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
              ConnectionString.closeconnection();
          }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide some ode for what you've done so far. You should show some effort, StackOverflow is not free code-writing service

Comment: check  my code in question tag

Comment: @Caldazar stack overflow is becoming a kind of "develop for me" tool

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here:

First, easier one, would be to alter your stored procedure, to add column and calculate presence in stored procedure

Second one is to add column to `DataTable` and use foreach to calculate value. Add it between `if` and setting of `DataSource` for `DataGridView`

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    DateTime baseTime = DateTime.Parse("09:45:00");
    dt.Columns.Add("PA", typeof(System.String)); //If this column already exists, just use the code from below to add value to it, and skip this row
    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
       DateTime t = DateTime.Parse(row[6].ToString()); //Your column 6 has Time, as visible from your code
       if(t<=baseTime)
          row["PA"] = "PRESENT";
        else
          row["PA"] = "ABSENT";            
        string txt = "Update attendance set pa = @value where attendance_id = @id";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("txt", ConnectionString.Getconnection());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", row[PA]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", row[9]); //column 9 is attendance id
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
   dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
   dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Code";
   dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Name";
   dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Department";
   dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Year";
   dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Month";
   dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Day";
   dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Time";
   dataGridView1.Columns[7].HeaderText = "Status";
   dataGridView1.Columns[8].HeaderText = "EMP/MACH-CODE";  
   dataGridView1.Columns[9].HeaderText = "Attendance_id";
   dataGridView1.Columns[9].Visible = false;
   dataGridView1.Columns[10].HeaderText = "P/A";
   // dataGridView1.Columns["Attendance_id"].Visible = false;
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
    dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
    this.dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.GhostWhite;
  }
```

Comment: DateTime t = DateTime.Parse(dt[6].ToString());   in dt[6] it shows 'Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.DataColumn;

Comment: @AliKhan sorry, fixed. Should have been row[6], not dt[6]. Edited code

Comment: thanks mate its working..one more thing how to insert complete present absent condition into database sql against same id..thanks

Comment: @AliKhan Write  similar to this `Update attendance set pa = value where attendance_id = id` query and execute it. You can do that in this same `foreach` loop. PS would appreciate if you mark this as answered ;)

Comment: yp sure thanks. can you please write this query into edit code so i am able to see where to write query  lines and "P/A" column name is originally in database table is status. so please elaborate

Comment: Added into foreach. Something like this should work for you

Answer (score 0):

One issue you may run into with the current approach is what do you do if the user “changes” one of the “Time” values in the grid? It would appear unnecessary to loop through all the rows again when only one row has changed. One possible solution is to wire up the “cell value changed” event. In this event, a check could be made to see if the “Time” value changed, and if so, update the “P/A” cell accordingly.

Above will solve the problem for when the user “changes” a “Time” value, however this will not set the “P/A” column when the grids data source is set. As this is a “computed” value (more below) it is not in the database. Therefore, it would be trivial to loop through all the rows and check each “Time” value and set the “P/A” values. OR, since we already have an event that will set the “P/A” value when the “Time” value is changed, it may be convenient to simply call the event for each row right after the grids data source is set. Granted this is not necessarily the best approach however, the code will only be called once.

Lastly, I must somewhat disagree with “saving” the “Absent/Present” values in the database. This is a “computed” value that will depend on what “Times” value is. If somewhere down the line, the “Time” value changes, then you better update the “P/A” value or the database becomes broken. It seems unnecessary to save this value in the database as you can get that information from the “Time” value. That is my opinion and if you want to save the “P/A” value then by all means save away.

The grids `CellValueChanged` event is below. A check is made to confirm the “Time” column was changed and the row is valid. More checks for a null or empty “Time” value. Lastly the time comparison to see if the cells time is less than “9:45:00”. Then sets the “P/A” cell value.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  // note: error checking (data error) is missing if the user types in an invalid date/time
  if (e.ColumnIndex == 2 && e.RowIndex >= 0 && !dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow ) {
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Time"].Value != null) {
      if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Time"].Value.ToString() != "") {
        DateTime cellTime = (DateTime)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Time"].Value;
        if (cellTime <= TargetTime)
          dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["P/A"].Value = "Present";
        else
          dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["P/A"].Value = "?-Greater than 9:45:00 A.M.";
      }
      else {
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["P/A"].Value = "Absent-empty";
      }
    }
    else {
      dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["P/A"].Value = "Absent-null NH";
    }
  }
}
```

Next is the extra code for setting the “P/A” column values after the grids data source is set. Loop through all the rows and fire the grids `CellValueChanged` event using the “Time” column index for the current row.

```
private void SetPACol() {
  for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++) {
    dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(this, new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(2, i));
  }
}
```

Putting it all together to test. Create some global variables: the grids `DataTable/GridDT`, `DateTime/TargetTime` set to today 9:45:00 A.M. When the form loads, Setup the `DatatTable` columns, fill the table with data, set the grids data source to the table and finally run the method that sets the “P/A” values.

```
private DateTime TargetTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 9, 45, 00);
private DataTable GridDT;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  GridDT = GetTable();
  FillTable(GridDT);
  dataGridView1.DataSource = GridDT;
  SetPACol();
}

private void SetPACol() {
  for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++) {
    dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(this, new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(2, i));
  }
}

private DataTable GetTable() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(int));
  dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(DateTime));
  dt.Columns.Add("P/A", typeof(string));
  return dt;
}

private void FillTable(DataTable dt) {
  dt.Rows.Add(1642, "Name1", new DateTime(TargetTime.Year, TargetTime.Month, TargetTime.Day, 9, 47, 00));
  dt.Rows.Add(1642, "Name2", new DateTime(TargetTime.Year, TargetTime.Month, TargetTime.Day, 9, 45, 00));
  dt.Rows.Add(1642, "Name3", new DateTime(TargetTime.Year, TargetTime.Month, TargetTime.Day, 9, 44, 59));
  dt.Rows.Add(1642, "Name4", null);
  dt.Rows.Add(1642, "Name5", new DateTime(TargetTime.Year, TargetTime.Month, TargetTime.Day, 9, 47, 00));
  dt.Rows.Add(1642, "Name6");
}
```

Good Luck!